# c strings: program reads characters following a space as blank spaces

Tags: c, c-strings

after the first space in a space-separated string, the program interprets all characters after the space as blank spaces:

ex:

```
char test1[] = "hello man";
char test2[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(test1); i++){
        if (test1[i] == ' ')
            continue;
        else
            test2[i] = test1[i];
    }
    printf("%s\n", test2);
```

this program outputs "hello", not "helloman".
How do you make it output "helloman"?

Comment: Your `test2` is not null-terminated. (unless it is global, but we don't have a way to know without [mcve]).

Comment: You can't use the same counter `i` for both arrays, because `test2` is "growing" slower than `test1` is iterated. You should have a separate counter and only increment it for non-spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding another counting index that doesn't increment when the character is a space.  for example.

```
int j = 0;  // added this
char test1[] = "hello man";
char test2[128];
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(test1); i++){
    if (test1[i] == ' ')
        continue;
    else {
        test2[j] = test1[i]; //changes here
        j++;                 // changes here
    } 
}
test2[j] = 0;                // added this
printf("%s\n", test2);
```

Comment: The body of the loop could be simplified to `if (test1[i] != ' ') test2[j++] = test1[i];`, could it not?  There are times to use `continue`; I'm not sure this is one of them.  You don't self-eveidently null-terminate `test2`.  And the loop control could be `for (int i = 0; test1[i] != '\0'; i++)`.

Comment: After the `for` loop, we need (e.g.) `test2[j] = 0;` to properly terminate `test2`, otherwise we have UB. And, I'd replace `i < strlen(test1);` with `test1[i] != 0;`

Comment: @alexpdev: +1: that's the response I was going to give; you beat me to it :)  FYI, I took the liberty of terminating test2[] with a null byte.  Also FYI, it might be useful to ensure the loop doesn't exceed the 127 characters allocated to test2[].

Comment: @CraigEstey  Good call. thanks paulsm4  for editing it.

Comment: While obviously code could be written differently and `continue` is not needed here, i feel like the person asking the question is a beginner and the explicit `continue` might make it easier for them to understand the code. Comments are a good place to put a hint like this, but in my opinion code in answers should probably contain only the differences necessary to fix the issue that person was having to make it easier for them to understand.

Comment: Note that doing `for (int i = 0;  i < strlen(test1);  ++i)` runs in O(n^2) time because it calls `strlen` on _every_ loop iteration [AFAICT, even with `-O2`] and `strlen` must rescan the string. It's actually O(n*(n/2)) --> O(n^2). But, `for (int i = 0;  test1[i] != 0;  ++i)` runs in O(n) time and the code size is 2x smaller.

Comment: using another iterator did not help the solve the issue

Comment: @RahelGerson  I made notes where changes where made.... make sure you did the same in your code btw the other answer is doing the exact same thing, so if that worked then so does this.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `test2` is most likely initialized to zero-value bytes (`0x0`) and because you skip the indices not only in `test1` but in `test2` as well.

Your memory looks similarly to this before you perform the for loop:

```
test1
[ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'a', 'n', 0x0 ]

test2
[ 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ... ] # 128 times
```

Then you copy char after char from `test1` to `test2` until you hit a space:

```
test1
[ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'a', 'n', 0x0 ]

test2
[ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ... ] # 128 times
```

But then, you want to skip the space, so you `continue` but the `0x0` character remains in `test2` as you move to the next index.

```
test1
[ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'a', 'n', 0x0 ]

test2
[ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0x0, 'm', 'a', 'n', 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ... ] # 128 times
```

As strings are NULL-terminated in C (so the end is marked by the `0x0` byte) it only prints the first part of the string - up until the `0x0` you left in there.

To avoid that you can use a separate index for your `test1` and `test2` arrays, and increment only the `test1` index (the `i` variable) when the space is found (without incrementing the `test2` index):

```c
int test2_index = 0;
char test1[] = "hello man";
char test2[128] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(test1); i++){
    if (test1[i] == ' ') {
        continue;
    } else {
        test2[test2_index] = test1[i];
        test2_index++;
    }
}
printf("%s\n", test2);
```

You can avoid such errors in the future by using a debugger and inspecting the memory areas of each array after every iteration of the for loop. Alternatively, since you only have 2 arrays and 2 indices and a for loop, you could just step over the algorithm with pen and paper, keeping track of values of every variable after every step.

Comment: See my comment under alexpdev's answer

Comment: This is peculiar, since i am pretty sure that alexpdev's answer contains pretty much the same changes as mine, and you have said that it did not work for you